# How to get form position as screen's Top Right corner?

Tags: delphi

I need to show my form on the right corner of the desktop. Please suggest me the way.

I have tried many ways but it fails.

Comment: 5k cowards visited this yet forgot to up-vote, star or do any action. BTW nowadays even SO recommends starring / up-voting if it just helped.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main complicating factor here is multiple monitors. With multiple monitors there may be no point on the desktop which is both top and right. What I would assume you might mean in that case would be the top of the right-most monitor.

Do it like this:

```
procedure MoveFormToTopOfRightmostMonitor(Form: TForm);
var
  i: Integer;
  Monitor, RightMostMonitor: TMonitor;
begin
  RightMostMonitor := Screen.Monitors[0];
  for i := 1 to Screen.MonitorCount-1 do
  begin
    Monitor := Screen.Monitors[i];
    if Monitor.Left+Monitor.Width > RightMostMonitor.Left+RightMostMonitor.Width then
      Monitor := RightMostMonitor;
  end;
  Form.Left := Monitor.Left+Monitor.Width-Form.Left;
  Form.Top := Monitor.Top;
end;
```

Comment: @rakesh I just fixed an error in the code. I was setting `Form.Top` incorrectly. Use the version you see now.

Comment: @rakesh If this is the answer to your question please remember to accept it. You seem to have forgotten this step lately.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
procedure TmainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 mainForm.left:= screen.Monitors[Screen.MonitorCount-1].Width-mainForm.Width;
end;
```